# Insert all rows and columns from table A to B which not exist in B already

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following columns:

I want to add all columns and rows from one table (A) to table (B) where the articlenumber (Column named "articlenumber" in both tables) is not one article number in B already.

Let´s say:

Table A

```
|articlenumber|OrderNumber|ArticleNumber|PaymentType|Returned?|OrderDate |
|3            |1          |1            |credit     |No       |01.01.2016|
|4            |2          |3            |credit     |No       |30.02.2016|
|5            |1          |2            |cash       |No       |01.01.2016|
```

Table B

```
|articlenumber|OrderNumber|ArticleNumber|PaymentType|Returned?|OrderDate |
|1            |1          |1            |cash       |Yes      |01.01.2016|
|2            |2          |3            |credit     |No       |30.02.2016|
|3            |1          |1            |credit     |No       |01.01.2016|
```

Expected Outcome:

```
|articlenumber|OrderNumber|ArticleNumber|PaymentType|Returned?|OrderDate |
|1            |1          |1            |cash       |Yes      |01.01.2016|
|2            |2          |3            |credit     |No       |30.02.2016|
|3            |1          |1            |credit     |No       |01.01.2016|
|4            |2          |3            |credit     |No       |30.02.2016|
|5            |1          |2            |cash       |No       |01.01.2016|
```

Tried it already with this:

```
INSERT INTO B SELECT * FROM A Where A.articlenumber = B.articlenumber;
```

But this seem not correct

How can I do it? Thanks for your support!

Comment: Is this a solution which will work?   `INSERT INTO B SELECT * FROM A WHERE articlenumber NOT IN (SELECT articlenumber FROM B);`

Comment: Are you using some kind of weird case-sensitive version of MySQL. It's not normally possible to ascribe the same name to two columns in the same table.

Answer (score 1):

Apply unique key on  `articlenumber` column

Then

```
insert ignore into B(column_names)
select column_names from a;
```

Comment: is not possible to apply unique key on articlenumber

Answer (score 0):

Try a left outer join of the form

```
INSERT INTO B SELECT A.* FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.articlenumber = B.articlenumber
WHERE B.articlenumber IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

you need not equal (<>) to get this like

```
INSERT INTO B SELECT A.* FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.articlenumber <> B.articlenumber
```

or you can also use this

```
    INSERT INTO B SELECT * FROM A 
    WHERE articlenumber NOT IN (SELECT articlenumber FROM B);
```